# What is planned for the tf model garden?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-model-garden

First, thanks for a great library.  While it helps with lots of great implementations, its seems that at least some parts of it do not keep up with the pace of tensorflow development.

What is planned for object detection stuff? Will tf-slim be replaced with something alive? Is tf2 support planned?

Answer (score 0):

The official repository provides a collection of example implementations for SOTA models using the latest TensorFlow 2's high-level APIs.

The TensorFlow Model Garden team is actively working on providing more TensorFlow 2 models.

Please read this blog for more information.
https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/03/introducing-model-garden-for-tensorflow-2.html

Please also check the GitHub repository to find more news.
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official#more-models-to-come

Comment: Oh, there seem to only be ResNet. I'm curious about all of code base of the object detection API

Answer (score 0):

Please check the milestone for Object Detection API at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/milestones.

It will support TensorFlow 2 by early July.